# The pixels are tearing after rendering. What to do?

Tags: rendering

The pixels are tearing after rendering. What to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have the shading for that object set to 'Flat'.  In the 3D view press t to bring up the Tool Shelf and find shading (under tools).  Click on 'Smooth'.  See if that changes the render.

eh five